# Solving 6 non-linear equations for 6 variables not working

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, algebra, equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of 6 non-linear equations for 6 variables but the notebook is continuously running for 2 days. What am I doing wrong? (Notebook attached)

```
exp1 = ExpandAll[(xd1 - x1)^2 + (yd1 - y1)^2 + z1^2 == h1^2];
exp2 = ExpandAll[(xd2 - x2)^2 + (yd2 - y2)^2 + z2^2 == h2^2];
exp3 = ExpandAll[(xd3 - x3)^2 + (yd3 - y3)^2 + z3^2 == h3^2];
exp4 = ExpandAll[((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 + (z1 - z2)^2)^(1/2) + ((x2 - x3)^2 + (y2 -y3)^2 + (z2 - z3)^2)^(1/2) == ((x1 - x3)^2 + (y1 - y3)^2 + (z1 - z3)^2)^(1/2)];
exp5 = ExpandAll[((z2 - z1)/(((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 + (z1 - z2)^2)^(1/2))) == ((z3 - z2)/(((x2 - x3)^2 + (y2 - y3)^2 + (z2 - z3)^2)^(1/2)))];
exp6 = ExpandAll[((z3 - z1)/(((x1 - x3)^2 + (y1 - y3)^2 + (z1 - z3)^2)^(1/2))) == ((z3 - z2)/(((x2 - x3)^2 + (y2 - y3)^2 + (z2 - z3)^2)^(1/2)))];

NSolve[{exp1, exp2, exp3, exp4, exp5, exp6}, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3}, Reals]
```

Comment: @dxiv Why can I not use the collinearity condition as an equation?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread what you were solving for. Comment removed.

Answer (score 2):

(*Not an answer, but too long for a comment*.)

Let `xk, yk, zk` define point `Pk`, then by the equality case of the triangle inequality `exp4` means the three points `P1, P2, P3` are collinear, with `P2` between `P1` and `P3`.

This is equivalent to `P2 = a P1 + (1-a) P3` for some `a ∈ [0,1]`, and in that case `exp5` and `exp6` follow, so the two last equations are redundant.

Then, the ratio `a` can be determined from the `zk` coordinates as `a = (z3 - z2) / (z3 - z1)`. When the calculated `a` falls within the permissible interval `[0,1]`, the remaining equations are:

```
  (xd1 - x1)^2 + (yd1 - y1)^2 + z1^2 == h1^2
  (xd2 - a x1 - (1-a) x3)^2 + (yd2 - a y1 - (1-a) y3)^2 + z2^2 == h2^2
  (xd3 - x3)^2 + (yd3 - y3)^2 + z3^2 == h3^2
```

This is a system of 3 equations with 4 unknowns `{x1, y1, x3, y3}`. In the general case, it can have none, several, or infinitely many solutions, though not necessarily pretty to calculate.